# Change list title on all lists with a certain name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

My setup is like this.

Application

- http://sharepoint

Site collection

- http://sharepoint/vendors/01

Sites

- http://sharepoint/vendors/01/vendor_a
- http://sharepoint/vendors/01/vendor_b
- ...

Each new site is created with a given number of pre defined lists. Each list has a title.

Lists

- http://sharepoint/vendors/01/vendor_a/lists/firstlist/allitems.aspx (First list)
- http://sharepoint/vendors/01/vendor_a/lists/secondlist/allitems.aspx (Second list)

We now have some thousand sites, and the need to change the title for "First list" has come. The problem is that it is only possible to do this through SP GUI by changing the sites one by one, which is very time consuming.

I guess there is a possibility to do this using PowerShell. Do anyone have any examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is iterate through all web sites in all site collections and look for a list called "First List" and then change it's name. Here is an example:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

$WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sharepoint"
if ($WebApp -ne $null)
{
    foreach ($site in $WebApp.Sites) 
    {
        foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
        {
            $list = $web.Lists["First List"];

            if ($list -ne $null)
            {
                $list.Title = "New Title";
                $list.Update();
            }            
        }
    }
}
```